# Proof for index of pair of operators

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $P$ and $Q$ be a pair of orthogonal projections on a separable Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$, such that $P-Q$ is compact and $(P-Q)^{2n-1}$ is trace class for some $n\in\mathbb{N}_{\geq0}$.

Claim: $Tr((P-Q)^{2n+1})=\dim(\ker(P-Q-I))-\dim(\ker(Q-P-I))$

How do you show this claim?

I have already shown that $Tr((P-Q)^{2n+1})=Tr((P-Q)^{2m+1})$ for all $m\geq n$.

Next, I am supposed to somehow use the fact that $-1\leq P-Q \leq 1$ to show that: $$ Tr((P-Q)^{2n+1})=Tr((P-Q)^{2m+1})=\lim_{m\to\infty}Tr((P-Q)^{2m+1})\stackrel{??}{=}\dim(\ker(P-Q-I))-\dim(\ker(Q-P-I)) $$

However, I'm not even sure what $-1\leq P-Q \leq 1$ means. Is it in the sense that $I-P+Q\geq0$ and $P-Q+I\geq0$, meaning both are self adjoint operators with spectrum on the non-negative real half-axis? How does that help me when looking at the limit? The closest thing I can think of is that if $P-Q$ is trace class then $$Tr(P-Q)=\sum_{k}<(P-Q)e_k,e_k>=\sum_{k}<Pe_k,Pe_k>-\sum_{k}<Qe_k,Qe_k>$$ where $\{e_k\}_k$ is some orthonormal basis of $\mathcal{H}$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone will ever wonder about this in the future:

1) $-1\leq P-Q\leq 1$ implies $\sigma(P-Q)\subseteq[-1,1]$.

2) $P-Q$ is compact, so that it has an ON eigenbasis $\{e_l\}$ with eigenvalues $\{\lambda_l\}.$  Write $$ \lim_{m\to\infty} Tr((P-Q)^{2m+1}) = \lim_{m\to\infty} \sum_{l} <e_l, (P-Q)^{2m+1} e_l> \\  = \lim_{m\to\infty} \sum_{l} \lambda_l^{2m+1}   $$
Since all eigenvalues are in the unit disc, in the limit, only $+1$ and $-1$ will survive and we will get the difference of their multiplicity, which is precisely $$\dim(\ker(P-Q-1))-\dim(\ker(P-Q+1))$$.

3) But the trace is independent of the power $m$ we pick as long as it is larger than $n$, so the result follows.